# Hide list of MySQL databases

Tags: centos, mysql

I'm trying to configure MySQL 5.1 on CentOS 6.6 in such a way that users will not be able to see databases to which they do not have any privileges. If they execute the command [SHOW DATABASES] it should only return a list of databases to which they have access privileges (as per the [db] table in the [mysql] privileges database). Any other database should not appear in the list.

I have tried the grant/revoke privileges commands in MySQL, but with no luck. I also tried using [skip-show-database] in my.cnf, but it causes an error (no list at all is displayed) unless [Show_db_priv] is enabled for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use grant command in sql in the correct way as follow, you can archive what you want.

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
mysql> create database test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> grant all on test.* to 'user01'@'%' identified by 'password01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
 mysql -u user01 -p  
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 44
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The above output is this test i did

Answer (score 2):

Add " `--skip-show-database`" to the startup script of MySQL or add it to the MySQL configuration file.

Grant the SHOW DATABASES privilege only to the users you want to use this command

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html

To disable the usage of the "SHOW DATABASES" command, the following parameter should be added in the [mysqld] section of the /etc/my.cnf:

```
 [mysqld]
 skip-show-database
```

Comment: I tried this already, but it hides the entire list. What I want to do is have the list displayed, but only containing the databases to which the user has privileges.

Comment: Note that this is "security" by obfuscation: by disabling `show databases` you still allow to select a database for which you know the name, e.g. `\u information_schema`